# Docker container install -g copy to other container

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I am installing Express in a container.
I need the smallest development container and I am using a full container to install the dependencies

```
        # container to install dendencies
        FROM node:10 as installer
        WORKDIR /src
        COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
        # install all dependencies
        RUN npm install
        # i need nodemon as global
        RUN npm install -g nodemon

        # working container 
        FROM node:10-alpine
        RUN mkdir /src
        WORKDIR /src
        # copy everything (node_modules)
        COPY --from=installer /src .
        COPY . .
        EXPOSE 3000
        CMD ["nodemon", "start"]
```

1. I copied all the node_modules but how can I copy the global `-g nodemon` ?
2. How can I remove the "installer" container after the installation process?

Comment: why don't you install nodemon in the second container

Comment: @EmircanOk It installs but the `node_modules` are not copied from the first container

Comment: Yes, I know. But you install nodemon in the first container, you can install it in the second container. @roll